# Redirect all undefined subdomains using Caddy

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

Let's say my Caddyfile defines two sites: `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`.

What should I do so that **any** subdomain other than these two is redirected to a.example.com?  For example, going to `c.example.com` or `xyz.example.com` should redirect to `a.example.com`

In other words, I want something like a 404 rule but for non-existent subdomains rather than non-existent files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Point your DNS A/AAAA records for *.example.com to your server.

```
a.example.com {
    # handle here
}
b.example.com {
    # handle here
}
*.example.com {
    redir https://a.example.com
}
```

You handle the `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` domains as you normally would, and set up a [`redir`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/redir) for `*.example.com` to `https://a.example.com`. Note that Caddy will automatically setup a redirect from `http` to `https` so that isn't needed.

Because you are using a wildcard domain in your Caddyfile, you can either use Caddy's on-demand TLS (which will fetch a certificate for that subdomain whenever such a request is received) or use a wildcard certificate (which requires the DNS challenge).

#### On-demand TLS

```
*.example.com {
    tls {
        on_demand
    }
}
```

There are some [pitfalls to this approach](https://caddy.community/t/serving-tens-of-thousands-of-domains-over-https-with-caddy/11179) which make wildcard certificates more attractive:

- Clients can abuse the setup to get as many certificates as they want, resulting in disk / memory exhaustion.
- Rate limiting by certificate authorities

#### Wildcard certificates

```
*.example.com {
    tls {
        dns cloudflare {env.CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_TOKEN}
    }
}
```

To use the DNS challenge, you need to

1. Use a nameserver that supports programmatic access
2. Build Caddy with a provider for that nameserver configured. For example, for Cloudflare you could build with https://github.com/caddy-dns/cloudflare (`xcaddy build master --with github.com/caddy-dns/cloudflare`) and save the token in the environment variable CLOUDFLARE_AUTH_TOKEN.